# I am a former model

Tags: riddle, wordplay, story

A long time ago, I used to be a model,
Even though I was a bit thick boned,
I'd dress in casual clothes like everyone else,
I could have been a thousand different things, I was way ahead of my time,
It pains me to think I should have been a singer instead,

Nowadays, I'm not as mobile as I used to be,
People treat me like I'm a dinosaur,
And my bills are really adding up,
I'm not fooling myself, I don't want your pity,
At least my immune system hasn't failed me yet,

Who / what am I?

Comment: I sense something "mobile", which I'm not familiar with...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could be

> the letter **T**

A long time ago, I used to be a model,

> Ford Model T

Even though I was a bit thick boned,

> T-bone steak

I'd dress in casual clothes like everyone else,

> T-shirt

I could have been a thousand different things, I was way ahead of my time,

> T-1000, from the *Terminator* series (from OP)

It pains me to think I should have been a singer instead,

> T-Pain

Nowadays, I'm not as mobile as I used to be,

> T-Mobile

People treat me like I'm a dinosaur,

> T-Rex

And my bills are really adding up,

> T-bill i.e. Treasury bill

I'm not fooling myself, I don't want your pity,

> Mr. T’s “I pity the fool” (from OP)

At least my immune system hasn't failed me yet,

> T cell